# Javascript inner loop stops outer loop on first occurence

Tags: javascript

I have nested two for loops like below. But the inner loop stops the outer loop in the first occurence. On execution,the below code gives only my 13th row in grey color where the expected behaviour is to see the 13th,14th and 15th row in grey color.

```
 var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
 for(var i = 0, max = rows.length;i < max;  i++)
 {

     var cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
     if (rows[i].cells[4].innerHTML == "Asset Removed")
      {
        for(var inner = 0, max = rows[inner].cells.length;inner < max;  inner++)
         {
         cells[inner].style.backgroundColor = "grey";
         }

      }
 }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Name `max` in the inner loop to something else.

Comment: @Kernel.. That worked.I dint notice that variable actually.Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(var i = 0, max = rows.length;i < max;  i++)
    for(var inner = 0, max = rows[inner].cells.length;inner < max;  inner++)
```

The `max` variable in the inner loop is the same as in the outer loop, hence overwriting its values, thus causing the `i < max` end condition to become unreliable.

Answer (score 2):

You are using same variable in inner and outer loops. `in javascript last assigned value is taken by variable as final  value` so change the `inner loop max variable to some another name`. try this one.

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
 for(var i = 0, max = rows.length;i < max;  i++)
 {

     var cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
     if (rows[i].cells[4].innerHTML == "Asset Removed")
      {
        for(var inner = 0, max1 = rows[inner].cells.length;inner < max1;  inner++)
         {
         cells[inner].style.backgroundColor = "grey";
         }

      }
 }
```

I have changes the inner loop `max` variable to `max1`